# Angular 5 one production build deployment on multiple sites

Tags: angular, build

Angular 5  one production build deployment on multiple sites

want to generate an angular build that should work on any locations/domains. is this possible with a single build generation .?

I am generating build using below command

```
ng build --prod --base-href="www.site1.com/app-name/web"
```

similarly for other sites

```
ng build --prod --base-href="www.site2.com/app-name/web"
ng build --prod --base-href="www.site3.com/app-name/web"
```

I want to generate build once so that I can deploy in multiple locations.

any one come across.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single Command that generates Build for App Builds

```
ng build --prod --base-href="/cms-dev/" --output-hashing=all
```

If you are getting any Build issues to want to ignore you can add below option to command.
--aot=false

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the whole URL in the `base-href`. Just use `/app-name/web`

Comment: can we use the dist files of one site can be used for another site.? , i am getting some path issues

Answer (score 0):

`--base-href` flag helps adding `<base href="/">` tag to your html file. This helps in resolving the relative urls for the resources (REST API, Images, JS etc.) in your applications.

I am not clear what "www.site1.com" is in your base href? is it a directory or server name?

Usually for any web application url, you have following important parts:

`[protocol]://[HostName]:[port]/[AppName]`

If port is not provided it will use default port depending on the protocol (http uses 80 as default port)

Few Examples:-

`http://www.site1.com/app-name/web`

`http://www.site1.com/my-app/web`

`http://www.site2.com:8080/app-name/web`

`https://www.site3.com/my-app`

The important thing to notice is that your web server exposes an end point(protocol+host+port) where your web application can be hosted. Your application can then have further sub applications accessible under different path (see the example url #1 and #2).

Now if you are trying to run same application on different web servers then just provide the application directory to the base-href parameter.

And if you are trying to run multiple sub applications under same web server then you have to generate different builds providing different values to `--base-href` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the your package.json to look like

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build_site1": "ng build --prod --base-href='www.site1.com/app-name/web'--output-path=dist/site1",
    "build_site2": "ng build --prod --base-href='www.site2.com/app-name/web'--output-path=dist/site2",
    "build_site3": "ng build --prod --base-href='www.site3.com/app-name/web'--output-path=dist/site3",
    "build_all": "npm run build_site1 && npm run build_site2 && npm run build_site3"
 }
```

and then run

```
npm run build-all
```

you will have all your built projects in different subfolders or `dist`

Comment: cant we use the dist files of one site can be used for another site.?

Comment: see that the folders dist/site1, dist/site3, dist/site3 exist. You will have to use the files in each folder to each server

Comment: i am looking for a solution generate once and use it on multiple sites. is that possible .?